# Expo-splash-screen and expo-app-loading Breaks the Android Build and Not able to build successfully

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Expo-app Loading breaks the android build in reactnative apps.When we run npm run android..the following build error occurs

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve project :expo-splash-screen.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :expo-splash-screen:
> - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Expected to Build Successfully and run on Android Devices but encounter something with expo-app-loading and expo-splash-screen.